# Getting error while trying to send an email with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

I want to send an email with Laravel. I am not sure what am I doing wrong.

Here is my Mail:

```
public function __construct()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('test@test.de')
                  ->view('emails.testemail');
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function send_email_test(){
Mail::to("my_email@mail.net")->send(new testemail());
}
```

Here is how I try to test it:

```
Route::get('/sendemailtext','testcontroller@send_test_email');
```

Here is the error:

```
Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message ""
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need check your SMTP details

Comment: @DsRaj Did and solved it. Also my emails go to Spam :(

Comment: Try some different name in subject and From

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a shot. It should work.

```
<?php
//activation is a blade for email inside emails folder
//$email is destination email ex: my_email@mail.net
//other things are pretty clear, I giess
Mail::send('emails.activation', $data , function($message) use ($email)
{   
    $message->from('no-reply@mydomain.com', 'Name of Email Sender');
    $message->to($email)->subject('Email Subject');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do like this

```
$user_email = 'my_email@mail.net';
Mail::send('emails.testemail', array(), function($message) use ($user_email)
{
  $message->from('test@test.de', 'From');
  $message->to($user_email)->subject('Test mail');
});
```